# why the parameter come out in my UI page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have no idea why the parameter suddenly come out at my role create page. After i add the permission checkbox there then it appear.

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Create Roles") %>
<h1 class="dashboard">Create Role</h1>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_with(model: @role, local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= @permissions.each do |permission|%>
   <%= check_box_tag 'permission_ids[]', permission.id %>
   <%= f.label :permission_name, permission.name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :company_id , value: 2%>

  <%= f.submit "Create Role", class: "btn btn-primary bottom" %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Parameter show at role create page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbF9K.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are currently seeing the string output of the `each` method because you're using `<%= @permissions.each ...`

Instead use the "silent" `<%` as you do for `end`:

```
<% @permissions.each do |permission| %>
```